# How To Click A button in Other Sheet use react-navigation (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

Here is a slice of my profile.js page which contains the input form. When the submit button is pressed, I want when moving the page to another page at the same time pressing the button on that page.

```
Submit = () => {
let reg = /^[ A-Za-z]+$/; //hanya input karakter
const {
  NikKtp,
  Nama,
  JenisKelaminNama,
  TempatLahir,
  TanggalLahir,
  Alamat,
  NoTelephon,
  NamaPropinsi,
  NamaKabKota,
  NamaKecamatan,
  NamaKelurahan,
  MitraKelompokNama,
} = this.state;
if (
  NikKtp == "" ||
  Nama == "" ||
  JenisKelaminNama == "" ||
  TempatLahir == "" ||
  TanggalLahir == "" ||
  Alamat == "" ||
  NoTelephon == "" ||
  NamaPropinsi == "" ||
  NamaKabKota == "" ||
  NamaKecamatan == "" ||
  NamaKelurahan == "" ||
  MitraKelompokNama == ""
) {
  Alert.alert("Data Tidak Boleh Kosong");
} else if (reg.test(Nama) === false || reg.test(TempatLahir) === false) {
  Alert.alert("Nama & Tempat Lahir tidak boleh diisi number");
  return false;
} else {
  this.setState({ vLoader: true });
  fetch(
    "https://allapi.azurewebsites.net/0.ap1/development/petanipintar.com/Profil(D).php?RegisterId=" +
      this.state.RegisterId +
      "&UserId=" +
      this.state.UserId,
    {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        Accept: "aplication/json",
        "Content-type": "aplication/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        NikKtp: NikKtp,
        Nama: Nama,
        JenisKelaminNama: JenisKelaminNama,
        TempatLahir: TempatLahir,
        TanggalLahir: TanggalLahir,
        Alamat: Alamat,
        NoTelephon: NoTelephon,
        NamaPropinsi: NamaPropinsi,
        NamaKabKota: NamaKabKota,
        NamaKecamatan: NamaKecamatan,
        NamaKelurahan: NamaKelurahan,
        MitraKelompokNama: MitraKelompokNama,
      }),
    }
  )
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((res) => {
    Alert.alert("Success");
    this.setState({ vLoader: false });
    this.props.navigation.navigate("MenuUtama", [ this.ButtonSection() ]);
    // this.props.navigation.goBack();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

};

This is the page I want to make my react navigation destination, in it is the button script I want to press.

```
 ButtonSection = () => {
  this.getMitraId();
```

};

Can anyone help me to slove this issues?

Answer (score 0):

In the target screen under `useEffect` add your script you want to run

eg:

// Functional Component

```
useEffect(()=>{
    // your code
},[]);
```

// Class based Component

```
componentDidMount() {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: sorry, but this solution make me have other trouble. Your soulution make useeffect executing repeatedly.

Comment: did you pass an empty dependency array https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#useeffect

Comment: I think OP is using class component because of `this.setState`.

Comment: Ohh didnt notice in that case @Billie use componentDidMount

Comment: componentdidmount can't run my code correctly. if i use componentdidupdate, yeah my code was running, but same with the useeffect make  my code  executing repeatedly. that make my project crashes.